# Construction of a model of $ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC)$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

By Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, the following assertion is true in ZFC:
$$
Con(ZFC)\rightarrow Con(ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC))
$$
Considering the completeness theorem, this assertion is equivalent to that one can always construct a model of $ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC)$ from a given model of $ZFC$. Is there any concrete construction of the new model, just like the constructible universe and forcing method?

Comment: This requires changing the set of natural numbers, so it's unlikely there will be a nice construction, and certainly no transitive model. There is, however, a nice construction of a transitive model of “ZFC + ‘ZFC has no transitive model’” from one of ZFC, namely, take smallest transitive model of ZFC (which is of the form $L_α$, where $α$ is the smallest ordinal for which this is indeed a model of ZFC).

Comment: Since $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is consistent, we can find (in a larger language) a consistent complete theory $T$ with the witness property such that $T\supseteq\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$. The ($\{\in\}$-reduct of the) term model of $T$ is then a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$. Of course this works for *any* consistent theory $S$ (note that the only noncomputable step is passing from the original theory to the complete consistent extension with the witness property).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I want a construction that only uses the information of the model itself. Noice that $ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC)+\neg Con(ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC))$ can have a model when $ZFC$ is consistent. If $M$ is a model of $ZFC+Con(ZFC)+\neg Con(ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC))$ (I am not sure if it is possible), does your construction work?

Comment: @KaHo Since the completeness theorem is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, for any theory $T$ and any structure $M$ if $M\models \mathsf{ZFC}+Con(T)$ then $M$ can perform an "internal" Henkinization argument and so there is an $a\in M$ which is a model of $T$. (More accurately, $M$ thinks $a$ is a model of $T$, and by the niceness of first-order logic $a$ actually is a model of $T$ in reality.) Maybe I'm not understanding what you're asking?

Comment: @NoagSchweber Just forget my last comment; it is stupid. I was actually thinking of a construction that uses the elements of the original model transfinitely, just like the two constructions that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @KaHo Well, since making a theory go from "consistent" to "(apparently) inconsistent" involves changing the natural numbers, we have to "break the ordinals" somehow. This is a fundamental difference in flavor.

Comment: @KaHo Put another way, $M$ and the new model can't agree on the $\Delta_0$ theory of $\omega$. This means that they really can't fit together nicely. By contrast, both inner models and forcing yield **end extensions** (with the original model sitting "on top" or "on bottom" respectively). So there's a "coherence" which inner models and forcing allow (indeed, guarantee) but nothing similar for internal inconsistency can hope to achieve.

Comment: This probably is unsatisfyingly silly, but it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there is a concrete—computable, even—procedure which given a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ produces a model of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$. Namely, suppose $\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) + \neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}))$. Under such a setting, the identity functor on models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ takes as input an arbitrary model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and outputs a model of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$.

Answer (score 3):

As has been discussed in the comments, there is no inner model or forcing-like construction that will give you a model, since the collection of natural numbers needs to grow.

You'll have to tell me if this is 'natural' enough, but by modifying the construction mentioned by Joel David Hamkins [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51754/clearing-misconceptions-defining-is-a-model-of-zfc-in-zfc/51786#51786), we can get the following:

> **Proposition.** There is a formula $\varphi(x)$ in the language of set theory such that for any $V \models \mathsf{ZFC}$, there is a unique $a \in V$ satisfying $\varphi(x)$ and this $a$ is always (externally) a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}+ \neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$.

*Proof:* As Noah Schweber mentioned in the comments, by standard (computable) procedure, for any theory $T$, we can find an expansion $H_{T} \supseteq T$ which is *term complete*, i.e., for every formula $\varphi(x,\bar{y})$ and tuple of closed terms $\bar{t}$, there is a closed term $s$ such that $H_{T}\vdash \exists x \varphi(x,\bar{t}) \to \varphi(s,\bar{t})$. The two most common ways to do this are adding Henkin constants and Skolemizing the theory. This implies that for any completion $T'$ of $H_T$, the *term structure* of $T'$ is a model of $T'\supseteq T$, where the term structure is the structure whose universe is the collection of all closed terms in the language of $T'$ with the interpretations of the atomic relations dictated by $T'$.

Another thing to note is that the construction of the language of $H_T$ can be done in such a way that if the language of $T$ is countable with a given enumeration, then the language of $H_T$ is countable with a given enumeration which is uniformly computable from the enumeration of the language of $T$. Also note that this language really only depends on the language of $T$, not on $T$ itself.

$\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that for any theory $T$, $\mathrm{Con}(T) \to \mathrm{Con}(H_T)$. (This is also provable in significantly weaker theories for the standard definitions of $H_T$.)

Let $\{\psi_i\}_{i<\omega}$ be a fixed computable enumeration of the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$, and let $T_i$ be $\{\psi_j\}_{i<j} + \neg \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ for each $i\leq \omega$ (so in particular, $T_\omega = \mathsf{ZFC} + \neg \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$). Through a combination of the reflection theorem and Gödel's incompleteness, you can show that for each $i<\omega$, $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash \mathrm{Con}(T_i)$. (Crucially though, we don't have that $\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash (\forall i<\omega)\mathrm{Con}(T_i)$ unless $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is inconsistent.) So by the above comment, we also have that for each $i<\omega$, $\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \mathrm{Con}(H_{T_i})$. Note that the choice of enumeration here matters, and we will get different models with different choices of enumeration.

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the common language of the $H_{T_i}$'s. By the above discussion we may assume that $\mathcal{L}$ has a fixed computable enumeration. By a standard argument, this implies that we have a computable enumeration of the collection of $\mathcal{L}$-sentences. Let $\{\chi_{i}\}_{i<\omega}$ be such an enumeration.

$\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that every consistent $\mathcal{L}$-theory $S$ has a unique 'leftmost' completion. What I mean by this is that we may regard complete $\mathcal{L}$-theories $S'$ as elements of $2^{\omega}$ by considering $\{i : S' \vdash \chi_i\}$. The leftmost completion is the one which is smallest in the lexicographical ordering on $2^\omega$. Such a completion exists by a typical compactness argument.

Okay so now pass to our model $V$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. $\mathsf{ZFC}$ implies that there is a maximal $k\leq \omega^V$ such that $V\models \mathrm{Con}(T_k)$. So in particular, if this $k$ is not $\omega^V$, then $V\models \neg \mathrm{Con}(T_{k+1})$. By the reflection theorem, $V \models \mathrm{Con}(T_i)$ for every externally finite $i$, so if $k<\omega^V$, then it must be a non-standard integer. Since $V$ thinks that $T_k$ is consistent, it also thinks that $H_{T_k}$ is consistent, and so it thinks that the leftmost completion $S$ of $H_{T_k}$ is consistent. $S$ has a term model $M$ which satisfies $S$ since $H_{T_k}$ is term complete.

So we can let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula that is satisfied if and only if $x$ is the term model of the leftmost completion of $H_{T_k}$ where $k\leq \omega$ is the largest for which $T_k$ is consistent. Although there are arbitrary choices in the construction of this formula, it does not have any parameters.

So to see that $M$ is externally a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$, note that we either have that $V \models k = \omega^V$ or that $k$ is a non-standard integer. In both cases, for every $i<\omega$, $V \models (M\models \psi_i)$, so since satisfaction of formulas is absolute, we have that $M$ models all of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$. $\square$

---

It is possible to make this construction slightly more 'canonical.' For example, if we start with $\mathsf{ZFC}+ V=L + \neg \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$, then there are natural definable Skolem functions, so we don't have to make any arbitrary choices to introduce them.

We still ultimately need to pick a completion of the Henkinized/Skolemized theory. We were able to do this in a definable way, but ultimately our completion depends heavily on the enumeration of the language. I doubt there is an 'enumeration invariant' way to choose a definable completion of a theory like $\mathsf{ZFC}$ or $\mathsf{PA}$, but maybe someone will show up and point out that there actually is one.